# Using ECS Fargate to run long processes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm migrating a software that I use to extract images from documents from iron.io to ECS Fargate, and the start of a container in EC2 is very slow, somethings takes 3 minutes for a container change the state from PENDING to RUNNING. Is it possible to improve this speed? I've searched about this subject, and there is a lack of information about why it takes so much time sometimes, and others are faster (but still very slow).

Answer (score 0):

The majority of time spent transitioning an ECS Fargate task from PENDING to RUNNING will be spent in pulling images over the network from a docker repository. Improving pull speed will most likely include examing the images being pulled and trying to reduce layer sizes if at all possible.

If your service is behind an ALB, you can also try adjusting the health check period and the healthy threshold counts to a lower number.

Comment: Hm, I see... but they need to pull the image EVERY time? It should be better create some sort of cache, no?